# How to increase series data label in highcharts packed bubble

Tags: highcharts

Using the sample provided by highcharts (less some data for easier visability) https://jsfiddle.net/mevbg82z/2/

I'm trying to make the bubble labels ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Brazil') bigger.

I've looked at the series API for packedbubble but haven't found a way to increase the size of the text in the bubbles through options  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.packedbubble

The only way I've found to do this is to write css, which doesn't handle scaling, doesn't center up, and generally seems hacky...

```
.highcharts-data-label text tspan {
    font-size: 24px
}
```

Whats the correct way to increase the size of these labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can set `fontSize` inside `plotOptions.packedbubble.dataLabels`

```
plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
        minSize: '20%',
        maxSize: '100%',
        zMin: 0,
        zMax: 1000,
        layoutAlgorithm: {
            gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
            splitSeries: true,
            seriesInteraction: false,
            dragBetweenSeries: true,
            parentNodeLimit: true
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}',
            filter: {
                property: 'y',
                operator: '>',
                value: 250
            },
            style: {
                color: 'black',
                textOutline: 'none',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontSize: '24px'
            }
        }
    }
},
```